# Ms Access connection string

Tags: .net, winforms, ms-access, connection-string

I am making a single user database app. I have created a database in Ms Access.
Here is the code I have written...

```
    OleDbConnection con;
    con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\testacc.accdb");
    OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from table1,data;",con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

It is working file on my system but it gives exception when I run it on other system because of the connection string,so my question is how can I create a connection string so it can run on other system as well.

Comment: You put a hard coded path to the .accdb. If you were to open a Explorer Window in the other computer and pasted in that path would it take you to the same place?

Comment: I know what is the problem where i am making mistake but i dont know how to fix it,i also tried to include .accdb in resources and gave the address to the resources folder now i can fetch data but i cant insert data.

Comment: What I used to do with access files was to create a specific directory on the machine and make sure its in both machines in the same relative directory... example: C:\Database\Access\database.accdb\

Comment: What type of application: ASP.NET or Winforms

Comment: its a winforms application,but what should i do if i dont have access to other's computer...

Comment: You said you can put it in as a resource but you cant write. Did you try setting permissions to read/write on the resources folder?